# file upload with other form data getting file undefined angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-fileupload

```js
'use strict';
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                    var modelSetter = model.assign;

                    element.bind('change', function() {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            modelSetter(scope, element.files[0]);
                            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);

        app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(data, file, uploadUrl) {
                var fd = new FormData();

                fd.append('name', data.name);
                fd.append('phone', data.phone);
                fd.append('experience', data.experience);
                fd.append('email', data.email);
                fd.append('position', data.position);
                fd.append('resume', file);

                var promise = $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    }
                });

                promise.then(function(response) {
                    var request = response.data;
                    if (request.success == "true") {
                        alert("Thank you for getting in touch with Mohar");

                        var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
                        inst.close();

                        $scope.userForm.$setPristine();
                        $scope.userForm.$setUntouched();
                    } else {
                        alert("Please try after sometime");
                        window.location.href = 'career.html';
                    }
                });
            }
        }]);

        app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload) {
            $scope.val1 = 'Sr. Python Developer';
            $scope.val2 = 'Jr. Python Developer';
            $scope.val3 = 'Sr. UI Developer';
            $scope.val4 = 'Jr. UI developer';
            $scope.val5 = 'Sr. Android Developer';
            $scope.val6 = 'Jr. Android Developer';
            $scope.val7 = 'Sr. Tester';
            $scope.val8 = 'Jr. Tester';
            $scope.val9 = 'Sr. Devops Engineer';
            $scope.val10 = 'Graphic designer';

            $scope.applyJob = function(val) {
                $scope.name = '';
                $scope.phone = '';
                $scope.experience = '';
                $scope.email = '';
                $scope.position = val
                console.log('clicked', $scope.position);
            }

            $scope.uploadFile = function() {
                var data = {
                    'name': $scope.name,
                    'phone': $scope.phone,
                    'experience': $scope.experience,
                    'email': $scope.email,
                    'position': $scope.position
                }
                var file = $scope.myFile;
                console.log('file is ', $scope.myFile)

                var uploadUrl = "career.php";
                fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(data, file, uploadUrl);
            };
        }]);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form name="userForm" class="job-form" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-payment" ng-model="name" name="name" id="name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Full Name" required />
                    <div ng-show="userForm.name.$dirty && userForm.name.$invalid || userForm.name.$touched">
                        <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required">Please enter name</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.pattern">Please enter valid name</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-payment" ng-model="phone" name="phone" id="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
                    <div ng-show="userForm.phone.$dirty && userForm.phone.$invalid || userForm.phone.$touched">
                        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.required">Please enter contact number</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.minlength">Please enter minimum 10 digit</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.maxlength || userForm.phone.$error.pattern">Please enter valid contact number</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-payment" ng-model="experience" name="experience" id="experience" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" placeholder="Experience" required />
                    <div ng-show="userForm.experience.$dirty && userForm.experience.$invalid || userForm.experience.$touched">
                        <p ng-show="userForm.experience.$error.required">Please enter total experience</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.experience.$error.pattern">Please enter only numbers</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-payment" name="email" ng-model="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
                    <div ng-show="userForm.email.$dirty && userForm.email.$invalid || userForm.email.$touched">
                        <p ng-show="userForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-payment" id="position" ng-model="position" ng-readonly="true" placeholder="Position" required />
                    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" placeholder="e.g: UI DEVELOPER" required> -->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-payment" fileModel="myFile" id="resume" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit pull-right" ng-click="uploadFile()">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <!-- ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" -->
        </form>
</div>
```

hello, I am using angularjs for validation & HTTP call. I want to post a file with some other form data like name, email, phone, experience, position etc.when I click on submit button It send an empty file. I don't understand what is wrong with this code please help i am new to angularjs. thank you in advance.

Comment: In the `filesModel` directive there the `modelSetter` function is being invoked twice. The first one is likely throwing an error and the second one gets skipped.

Answer (score 0):

In the `fileModel` directive, delete the erroneous line:

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ̶m̶o̶d̶e̶l̶S̶e̶t̶t̶e̶r̶(̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶,̶ ̶e̶l̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶.̶f̶i̶l̶e̶s̶[̶0̶]̶)̶;̶                         
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

In the template, instantiate the directive with [kebab-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles) not [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case):

```
<input type="file" class="form-control form-control-payment"
       ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶M̶o̶d̶e̶l̶=̶"̶m̶y̶F̶i̶l̶e̶"̶
       file-model="myFile"
       id="resume" required>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)